# about "plankton"

Tags: word-meaning

The word "plankton" is defined as "the very small forms of plant and animal life that live in water."

If you are looking at a single diatom or a small crustacean, could you say, "Look! This is **plankton**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The word you want is "**plankter**", though I doubt many native speakers know this word. I didn't until just now.

Merriam-Webster has this to say:

> **[plankton](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plankton) :** the passively floating or weakly swimming usually minute organisms (such as dinoflagellates, diatoms, copepods, radiolarians, and larval crustaceans and fish) of a body of water
> ***Note: An individual organism found in plankton is technically referred to as a plankter.***

> **[plankter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plankter) :** an individual planktonic organism (such as a dinoflagellate, diatom, copepod, or radiolarian)

Comment: How would someone who does not know the word "plankter" express the idea in my question?

Comment: @Apollyon — _Plankton Conference Port Townsend Marine Science Center 19 Aug 2010 — Can you imagine looking at a tiny **piece of plankton** through a microscope and trying to figure out what species it is?_

Comment: @Apollyon To be honest, if I wasn't talking to a marine biologist, I'd say something like, "a single plankton" and reasonably assume they wouldn't know it was technically wrong.

Comment: I have to wonder if even in the case of a marine biologist whether "plankter" is like data/datum, that it will only matter to the very strictest of pedants.

Comment: @gotube You don't think "a (single) plankton" is odd, if not ungrammatical?

Comment: @Apollyon I now know that it's ungrammatical, but no, it doesn't feel odd to me, just unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those "it actually never happens"

You can't easily see individual animals or plants in the plankton, unless you are using a microscope.  And if you are a scientist using a microscope you would be able to say "diatom" or "crustation" or whatever.

There is as much variety in the plankton as there is in a forest between the tree, the birds and the insects that live in the forest. It would be just as hard to find a single word that means "any of the living things that are found in a forest", because if you are close enough you'd just say "tree" or "bird" etc.

But if you really need a word then "piece of plankton" or even "a plankton" would probably suffice.